# Local variable referenced before assignment in If statement when calculating mean absolute error

Tags: python, numpy, if-statement, mse

I'm trying to add a weight to not penalize as much if prediction is greater than the actual in a forecast. Here's my code, however, I keep getting:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'under' referenced before assignment

```
import numpy as np

def mae(y, y_hat):
    if np.where(y_hat >= y):
        over = np.mean(0.5*(np.abs(y - y_hat)))
    elif np.where(y_hat < y):
        under = np.mean(np.abs(y - y_hat))
    return (over + under) / 2
```

I've tried setting 'under' to global but that doesn't work either. This is probably an easy fix though I'm more of an R user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So because of the `if` and `elif` statement, when you return `np.mean(over,under)`, either `under` or `over` isn't going to be defined. Therefore, you either need to initialize `under` and `over` with initial values or rework it because with you current logic only one of those variables will be defined.

### EDIT

So you changed it to `(over + under) / 2` as the return statement. Still one of them isn't going to be defined. So you should initialize them as 0. Such as:

```
import numpy as np

def mae(y, y_hat):
    under = 0
    over = 0
    if np.where(y_hat >= y):
        over = np.mean(0.5*(np.abs(y - y_hat)))
    elif np.where(y_hat < y):
        under = np.mean(np.abs(y - y_hat))
    return (over + under) / 2
```

Then they won't affect the output at all when not in use.

Comment: Ah, so basically over = 0, under = 0 before the if statement? Seems to be working now.

Comment: Yes. See response. Glad to hear that